# I tried this below code to set increment and decrement values in edittext field .But its not working why?

Tags: android, numbers, android-edittext, increment, decrement

```
package com.inc.increment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Increment extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
int a,b;    
Button b1,b2;
EditText editText;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_increment);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_increment, menu);
    return true;
}
    public void onClick(View v) {     

    // now perform the increment/decrement
    if (R.id.button1 == v.getId()) {

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
            a=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            b=a+1;
        String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
        editText.setText(s1);

    } else if (R.id.button2 == v.getId()) {

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
        int a=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            int b=a-1;
        String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
       editText.setText(s1);
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: `not working why ?` if you have any error then add or add value in edittext and see what happens ?

Comment: @AnoopVB post your logcat and give some description of your problem.

Comment: I alredy added 0 in <string name="edittext">0</string>

Comment: I given an answer, Have u tried it @ AnoopVB

Comment: @DipakKeshariya 07-07 12:33:05.476: D/AndroidRuntime(624): Shutting down VM
07-07 12:33:05.476: W/dalvikvm(624): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-07 12:33:05.494: E/AndroidRuntime(624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 12:33:05.494: E/AndroidRuntime(624): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: @SamirMangroliya thanks i got the answer error was i didn't set value in oncreate editText.setText("0");

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a default value set for timepicker_input? If its blank during activity onCreate, and the onclick will error out since parseInt will fail with Numberformatexception...

What's your error?

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya 07-07 12:33:05.476: D/AndroidRuntime(624): Shutting down VM
07-07 12:33:05.476: W/dalvikvm(624): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-07 12:33:05.494: E/AndroidRuntime(624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 12:33:05.494: E/AndroidRuntime(624): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: Thanks. U r right. I got the answer error was i didn't set value in oncreate editText.setText("0");

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code for that.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button b1, b2;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // now perform the increment/decrement
        if (R.id.button1 == v.getId()) {

            if (editText.getText().toString().equals(null)
                    || editText.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || editText.getText().toString().equals("null")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Some Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                int b = a + 1;
                String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
                editText.setText(s1);
            }
        } else if (R.id.button2 == v.getId()) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().equals(null)
                    || editText.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || editText.getText().toString().equals("null")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Some Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                int b = a - 1;
                String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
                editText.setText(s1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i got the answer error was i didn't set value in oncreate editText.setText("0");

Comment: Could U please explain this Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Some Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: if user not entered any value in edittext then "Enter Some Value" this message is display in toast and "Toast.LENGTH_SHORT" is for duration.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code, use below code and it will work.

```
package com.inc.increment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Increment extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
int a,b;    
Button b1,b2;
EditText editText;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_increment);
   editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);    
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_increment, menu);
    return true;
}
    public void onClick(View v) {     

    // now perform the increment/decrement
    if (R.id.button1 == v.getId()) {


            a=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            b=a+1;
        String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
        editText.setText(s1);

    } else if (R.id.button2 == v.getId()) {


         a=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
             b=a-1;
        String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
       editText.setText(s1);
    }       
  }
}
```

Don't create edittext instance in on click, it should be in oncreate

Comment: thanks i got the answer error was i didn't set value in oncreate editText.setText("0");

Comment: thanks i got the answer error was i didn't set value in oncreate editText.setText("0");